# Android How can I pass string values from database to TextView in another activity in Android?

Tags: android

I want to display values from my COLUMN_INGRIDIENTS column from my db to a TextView in another activity when a certain data on list in my Main activity is clicked.

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
package com.example.viewer;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends Activity {

public final static String TAG_INGRIDIENTS="com.example.getlistfromdb.INGRIDIENTS";


private recipelistHelper dbrecipelistHelper = null;
private Cursor ourCursor = null;
private recipeAdapter adapter = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    try
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);

    dbrecipelistHelper = new recipelistHelper(this);

    dbrecipelistHelper.createDatabase();

    dbrecipelistHelper.openDatabase();

    ourCursor=dbrecipelistHelper.getCursor();

    startManagingCursor(ourCursor);

    adapter = new recipeAdapter(ourCursor);

    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());   

        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}


private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 

{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

    {



        Intent i=new Intent(Main.this, Activity2.class);
        String ingridients = null;
        i.putExtra(TAG_INGRIDIENTS,ingridients);
        startActivity(i);

    }

};



class recipeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    recipeAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(Main.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public  void bindView (View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c)
    {
        recipeHolder holder = (recipeHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, dbrecipelistHelper);
    }
    @Override
    public  View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
        recipeHolder holder = new recipeHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }


}

static class recipeHolder {
    private TextView name=null;

    recipeHolder(View row){
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, recipelistHelper r){
        name.setText(r.getName(c));
    }

}
```

}

Activity2.java

```
package com.example.viewer;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Activity2 extends  Activity {

String ingridients = null;
String procedure = null;

private TextView txtIngridients = null;
private TextView txtProcedure = null;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    ingridients=this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Main.TAG_INGRIDIENTS);
    //procedure=this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Main.TAG_PROCEDURE);

    txtIngridients=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ingridientText);
    //txtProcedure=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.procedureText);



    txtIngridients.setText(ingridients);
    //txtProcedure.setText(procedure);


  }
}
```

view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ingridientText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="A" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `String ingridients = null;
        i.putExtra(TAG_INGRIDIENTS,ingridients);` what is that?you send null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `adapter.getItem` to get cursor of selected row in ListView :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Cursor selectedCursor=(Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
        // get  ingridients coulmn value from selectedCursor
        selectedCursor.moveToPosition(position);  
        String ingridients = dbrecipelistHelper.getName(selectedCursor);
        // your code here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but what is "<ingridients_Column_Name>" ? 
coz it gives an error says column '<ingridients_Column_Name>' does not exist. I try to change it with COLUMN_INGRIDIENTS but it also says does not exist

Answer (score 0):

In your onItemClickListener you assign null to your string:

```
String ingridients = null;
```

and pass this String to your next Activity. This will be null. You have to fetch your data before you initialize your ingridients variable and set it to the desired String.

Comment: I dont know how to fetch the data. Im a total beginner